# Convert internal.Writable to NodeJS.WritableStream

Tags: node.js, pcm, nodejs-stream, speaker

I want to output sound to my speaker using ytdl-core and fluent-ffmpeg

I get the sound from yt and use ffmpeg to convert it to pcm and now i want to pipe it to my speaker

[speaker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/speaker) uses `internal.Writable`

[naudiodon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/naudiodon) uses `NodeJS.WritableStream`

when piping to `speaker` everything works

when piping to `naudiodon` I get a typescript error and hear nothing

What is the difference between the two streams and can I convert them, because I need to use `naudiodon` because there I can specify my output device

##### Edit:

[WritableStream](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WritableStream) is a Web API and [internal.Writable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) is from Node.js

Can I convert a `Writable` to a `WritableStream`?

[Github Issue](https://github.com/Streampunk/naudiodon/issues/69)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `WritableStream` to apply actions to underlying `Writable`. Here is an example.

```
function toWebWritable<T extends Uint8Array>(writable: Writable): WritableStream<T> {
    return new WritableStream<T>({
        write(chunk, controller) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                console.log('Writing chunk:', chunk.length);
                const result = writable.write(Buffer.from(chunk), (error) => {
                    console.log('Write result:', result, error, chunk.length);
                    if (error) {
                        controller.error(error);
                        reject(error);
                    }
                });
                if (!result) {
                    writable.once('drain', resolve);
                } else {
                    resolve();
                }
            });
        },
        close() {
            // Assuming a graceful closure is desired:
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                writable.end(resolve);
                // If there's an error, it should be handled by listening to the 'error' event on the writable itself.
            });
        },
        abort(reason) {
            writable.destroy(asError(reason));
        }
    });
}
```